# highcharts xaxis combine date and time into datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, highcharts

HI I am just starting out trying to use Highcharts to display weather data from a mysql database. The database is running and I can run basic queries to extract data.
The problem I have is that the database stores date and time in separate columns and Highcharts needs a datetime field. How can I combine the two to give me a datetime.
I'm very much a newbie on this and have read loads of similar questions but nothing quite seems to fit to what I am looking to do.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you give an example of the format of date and time you have?

Comment: In your script where you communicate with data, you need to get two fields from database and then use any function which allows to concate strings and transform to timestamp. All depends what kind of technology you use to communicate with database (php / c# or other)?